# Pass one arraylist to another in wrapper class with interface

Tags: java

You have interface.

```
public interface Group {
    public void assemble();
}
```

You have two classes that implements that interface.

```
public class Block implements Group {

    public void assemble() {
        System.out.println("Block");
    }
}

public class Structure implements Group {
  // Collection of child groups.
  private List<Group> groups = new ArrayList<Group>();

  public void assemble() {
    for (Group group : groups) {
      group.assemble();
    }
  }

  // Adds the group to the structure.
  public void add(Group group) {
    groups.add(group);
  }

  // Removes the group from the structure.
  public void remove(Group group) {
    groups.remove(group);
  }
}
```

After you create objects:

```
Structure structure = new Structure();
Structure structure1 = new Structure();
```

and fill ArrayList in structure instance:

```
structure1.add(new Block());
structure1.add(new Block());
```

**you can pass: structure.add(structure1)**

But when you pass separately one ArrayList to another you must use addAll method:

```
List<Group> groups = new ArrayList<Group>();
List<Group> groups1 = new ArrayList<Group>();
groups1.addAll(groups);
```

---

My question is why this works?

---

<sub>Examples come from: http://javapapers.com/design-patterns/composite-design-pattern/</sub>

Comment: maybe it's due to ... otherwise you are just adding the pointer of the object to the list, not the actual elements in the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are **not** passing `ArrayList` you are passing `Structure`. `Structure` is no `ArrayList` it's a descendant of `Group` . And this structure has it's own `list` inside. With it's own implementation of `assemble()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Because you use addAll method. You added a list to another list. Why did you confuse?

```
    /**
 * Appends all of the elements in the specified collection to the end of
 * this list, in the order that they are returned by the
 * specified collection's Iterator.  The behavior of this operation is
 * undefined if the specified collection is modified while the operation
 * is in progress.  (This implies that the behavior of this call is
 * undefined if the specified collection is this list, and this
 * list is nonempty.)
 *
 * @param c collection containing elements to be added to this list
 * @return <tt>true</tt> if this list changed as a result of the call
 * @throws NullPointerException if the specified collection is null
 */
public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends E> c) {
Object[] a = c.toArray();
    int numNew = a.length;
ensureCapacity(size + numNew);  // Increments modCount
    System.arraycopy(a, 0, elementData, size, numNew);
    size += numNew;
return numNew != 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The two examples do very different things. When you do

```
structure.add(structure1);
```

You've added two levels of hierarchy here because you added *structure1* `Group` at level one below the `structure` itself if you think of this as a tree. The `Block`s that belong to `structure1` are at level two here still attached to *structure1*.

But when you do

```
groups1.addAll(groups);
```

You only get a single-level hierarchy here because you didn't add a `Group` but, all of its members instead, directly beneath `groups1` as siblings to any `Block`s that may have been its children.

Answer (score 0):

Because you instantiate groups1 as an ArrayList. 
When you created a Structure this is not an ArrayList.

I think what you "Could" be indicating is that you want do this:

```
   public List<Group> groups = new ArrayList<Group>();
```

Change the access modifier of the above to public.

You will then be able to do something along the lines of:

```
    structure.groups.addAll...
```